# Scraping tracklist

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a tracklist from a [website](http://www.electronic-battle-weapons.com/mix/solid-steel-palms-trax/). My relevant code is:

```
page.css('ol').each do |line|
  subarray = line.text.strip.split(" - ")
end
```

This makes the array take the first artist into the first index (as I want), but adds the track and the artist of track two into the second index like this:

```
subarray[0] = Rick Wilhite
subarray[1] = Magic Water [Still Music]
Edward
subarray[2] = Into A Better Future [Giegling]
Kassem Mosse
subarray[3] = Zolarem [Mikrodisko Recordings]
After Hours
```

I included the nested tag so my code reads:

```
page.css('ol li').each do |line|
  subarray = line.text.strip.split(" - ")
end
```

but this only seems to leave `subarray[0]` displaying `"Klara Lewis"` and `subarray[1]` displaying `"Shine [Editions Mego]"`, which is the last track on the tracklist. All other index values are blank.

A further complication is that I would like to remove the record label from what will end up being the track value. I believe the correct regular expression is `\[[\d\D]*?\]`, but I'm under the impression that this needs to be applied before the data goes into the array to avoid complications involved in iterating over arrays. I tried passing it as a second delimiter to split (along with `' - '`) which didn't work, and I also attempted to test it by changing my code to:

```
page.css('ol').each do |line|
  subarray = line.text.strip.split("\[[\d\D]*?\]")
end
```

but that also appears not to work. Can anyone help me on this or give me the right pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

`page.css('ol')` gives you the entire `<ol>` with every one of the `<li>` tags:

```
<ol>
  <li>Rick Wilhite...</li>
  <li>Edward...</li>
  ...
  <li>Klara Lewis...</li>
</ol>
```

When that one big chunk enters the `.each` loop, you're only running through the loop once. So when you apply the `.split(" - ")` method, `subarray` will be filled once with all the text separated by `-`.

On the other hand, `page.css('ol li')` gives you each individual `<li>`, like this:

```
  <li>Rick Wilhite...</li>
  <li>Edward...</li>
  ...
  <li>Klara Lewis...</li>
```

This time, you're running through the loop 17 times, once for each `<li>` tag. The first time through, `.split(" - ")` is applied to the text and stored in the `subarray` variable. The problem is that the next time through the loop, `subarray` is overwritten with the split text of the second `<li>`. So after the final time through, the only contents of the `subarray` variable is the split text of the final `<li>`: "Klara Lewis" and "Shine [Editions Mego]".

I think you've gotten the general idea of how to scrape from a website, but I recommend building your script more incrementally so you understand exactly what you're doing in each step. For example, use `puts` to check what `page.css('ol')` gives you and how it differs from `page.css('ol li')`. What happens when it goes through a loop? What do you get when you apply `.split()`? Building more slowly and exploring around to make sure you understand what you're doing will help you avoid hitting dead ends. Hope that helps!

Comment: Absolutely spot on again mate, totally get it now, got it working!! Much thanks!